# Correlation Network Analysis, Cut off value

Tags: cytoscape

How can I change the correlation cut off value in cytoscape? I can not find how to change it. It is in default +-0.95 and I want to change it to 0.6. I installed the correlation network app but there is no option for cut off value change.

Because of this default setting, there is not any nodes for correlated nodes that have cut of less than -0.95 and +0.95 and in the list of names and strengths, most of my data is excluded.

I want to have all correlated nodes with -0.6 and +0.6 to be included.

I appreciate to help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't get that app to work for me at all, but reading the old documentation for the Cytoscape 2.x plugin, I think you need to use the Histogram function, which allows you to set the cutoffs.